# Scatter plot with ggplot and predict() R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, predict

I'm not a R specialist, and I've to do some stuff with R... But I stacked even in simple tasks... Sorry if it is a basic question but I haven't seen any issues like mine here in stackoverflow...

I'm having a bad time here with ggplot2 and predict() in R.

If someone could help me I'll appreciate it =]

```
    setwd("/home/kaihami/Desktop/Python/RR_Bioinfo/")


library("ggplot2")

data_total <- data.frame(bac, Phylum, Domain, CDS, Total)

#model (Total)
modlinear <- lm(Total ~ CDS)
xmin <- min(logCds2)
xmax <- max(logCds2)
predicted <- data.frame(logCds2=seq(xmin, xmax, length.out=length(logCds2)))
predicted$Total <- predict(modlinear, predicted)

#Total RR (ln)geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y.hat), col=2)
ggplot(data_total, aes(x = CDS, y = Total, colour = Domain))+
  geom_point(size=3.2, alpha = 0.4) +
  theme_bw()+theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                   panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                   panel.border = element_blank(),
                   panel.background = element_blank(),
                   legend.title=element_blank(),
                   legend.key=element_blank()) +
  geom_abline(data = predicted)
```

With this code I got my graph that I want to, with the right axis and values...

But when I tried to put the regression line, I got a really bad graph, with the regression line dislocated... (sorry but I can't post images yet)

So I tried to check if my model was right and it was using summary(modlinear).

My question is, anybody here know how to fix it? Anybody ever experienced it?

Another silly question... What is the main difference between geom_abline and geom_line?

Comment: Start here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html  Look for method = "lm" and the se argument if you want confidence bands, That should replace most of your model fitting code.

Answer (score 0):

`geom_abline()` is like saying y=ax+b, and you specify the slope and intercept.

`geom_line()` plots a line fitting data. Check the [docs.ggplot2.org](http://docs.ggplot2.org) site as @Dennis commented.

So you have two options here. If your regression line is linear, use `geom_abline()` and specify your slope and intercept, or, if you want to plot predicted data, use `geom_line(data=predicted...)` and appropriate arguments. Make more sense?